# evaluate function limit by change of variable

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling with this limit, tried everything on it but can't treat this indeterminate form...

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow  0} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}$$

Ideally, I want to evaluate it using a change of variables, but every other method would be most welcome.

I thank you guys for your explanation and your help.

Comment: If $u=\dfrac1x$, then we have $$\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{\sin u}{e^u+1}.$$  What do you know about the convergence of this?

Comment: @AndrewChin That is not correct. The limit you've written can exist, but the one OP wrote still may not.

Comment: First, think about the same limit where the numerator is the constant $1$. How does the denominator behave depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative? For example, evaluate the denominator for $x=0.1$ and for $x=-0.1$.

Comment: @DonThousand Are you able to explain that to me in brief?

Comment: @AndrewChin The limit you've written is equivalent to $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin\frac1x}{e^{\frac1x}+1}$$That isn't exactly the limit OP is asking for.

Comment: Right on, I see your answer.  Would it be fair to say that if $\lim\limits_{u\to\infty} f =\lim\limits_{u\to -\infty} f = L$, then the limit would exist?

Comment: @AndrewChin That would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\frac1x$. The limit becomes $$\lim\limits_{y\to\pm\infty}\frac{\sin y}{e^y+1}$$Note that when $y\to-\infty$, $e^y+1\to1$, so the limit becomes $\lim\limits_{y\to-\infty}\sin y$ which does not exist, so the overall limit does not exist.

If you solely care about the limit as $x\to0^+$, then we consider $y\to\infty$ in our transformed limit, as below$$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\frac{\sin y}{e^y+1}$$ As $e^y+1\to\infty$, while $|\sin y|\leq1$, this limit equals $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The right limit exists and it is $0$ because the numerator is bounded and the denominator goes to $\infty$

The left limit does not exist because the denominator approaches $1$ while the  numerator does not have a limit as it jumps up and down between $1$ and $-1$

Thus the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\left|\frac{\sin(u)}{e^u+1}\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{e^u+1}\right|$$